# CORS + End of file reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a production environment (Rails 4.2 and nginx) that has been running for quite some time without any modifications. There is one endpoint on server A (e.g. app.myserver.com/header) that I'm calling from another server B (www.myserver.com) via AJAX.

Suddenly (starting from 5th April) the server A started randomly (so not on every request) throwing `end of file reached` errors. There was no recent change on server A or B.

At the same time (so every time the error happens) the browser (when opening page on server B that does AJAX call to server A) throws standard CORS error:

`Failed to load https://app.myserver.com/header: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.myserver.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.`

**Question:** Any idea where to look for the problem?

What puzzels me the most is that it's not happening consistently.

I would expect the error to be on server A, because if it was pure CORS error I would see that only in the browser, right?

Btw. here is my CORS setting in Rails app for that endpoint:

    `headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'https://www.myserver.com'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'`

And on the occasions the request succeeds, I do see the correct headers also in the browsers.

I was thinking if it could be related to a browser update that somehow changed the way CORS works, but I replicated the error both in Chrome and Firefox, and I would be surprised that they both pushed globally (my users are also getting the errors) an update that causes the same error on the same day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem, it was indeed on server A and was caused by a `end of file reached` that was being thrown by [another gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder), which was due to it using an API that stopped working. Or rather, was being phased out, so that's why it sometimes worked sometimes not.

To explain why CORS happened on the client side: it was due to the fact that when application threw an error it triggered a redirect to an error page that didn't have the proper headers.